# Update values in text input on form submission - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, input

I started learning asp.net to make a very simple web app which can manage the scheduled tasks of the machine where it runs.
I have created a very simple form in the .aspx file:

```aspx
<form id="form1" runat="server" OnClick="Form_Submit">
    <p>
        <input class="form-control" id="scheduleName"  type="Text" runat="server"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="form-control" id="checkschedule"  type="Text" runat="server"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Save" type="Submit" runat="server"  />
    </p>
</form>
```

I then have the following code on the corresponding .cs file

```
public partial class Content : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Form_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = scheduleName.Value;
        checkschedule.Value = test;
    }
}
```

I tested I can populate the inputs from the onload function (I will use it to show the list of schedules on the system)
But I cannot get to modify the value of checkschedule when I post the form from the browser - It doesn't change on my browser.

I guess I should notify that I've changed the value and send it back... but I cannot find a proper way to do it. Checked other answers but couldn't get my head around this.. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, using session - saved variables ( actually a better way of doing what I wanted to do)